# CSS before in the wrong place

Tags: html, css

I have a problem in the before of a div. I'm trying to position it at first, but it's going to the beginning of the parent div on the other side. What can I be doing wrong?

Html:

```css
.cart-item.free-delivery-warn .left {
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cart-item.free-delivery-warn .left p {
  text-align: right;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #543a5c, #452f4b);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.cart-item.free-delivery-warn .right-content {
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}

.cart-item.free-delivery-warn .right-content p {
  background: #bf2328;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 0 13px 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
}

.right-content:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 100%;
  left: -12px;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 12px 22px 0;
  border-color: transparent #bf2328 transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart-item free-delivery-warn">
  <div class="left">
    <p>Faltam apenas <span class="price-w">R$ 165,00</span> para você ganhar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-content">
    <p>Frete grátis&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-truck price-w"></i></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and what it's doing wrong:
[image: Arrow showing wrong position]

Comment: Most likely you want to give .right-content a relative position. IE: .right-content {position: relative;}

Comment: You  haven't added `position:relative` to the `.right-content` div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you use `position: absolute` and you want it to be relative to the container, you need to set the container to `position: relative`. Like this:

```css
.cart-item.free-delivery-warn .left {
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cart-item.free-delivery-warn .left p {
  text-align: right;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #543a5c,#452f4b);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.cart-item.free-delivery-warn .right-content {  
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}

.cart-item.free-delivery-warn .right-content p {
  background: #bf2328;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 0 13px 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
}

.right-content {
  position: relative;
}

.right-content:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 100%;
  left: -12px;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 12px 22px 0;
  border-color: transparent #bf2328 transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart-item free-delivery-warn">
  <div class="left">
    <p >Faltam apenas <span class="price-w">R$ 165,00</span> para você ganhar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-content">
    <p>Frete grátis&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-truck price-w"></i></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked! I just changed the 'bottom: 0' to 'top: 0' in the ': before' and it worked fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're so close, but you're just missing a `position: relative` on the parent.

Just be careful as `margin` will push it out of alignment.

Try this out:

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.cart-item.free-delivery-warn .left {
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cart-item.free-delivery-warn .left p {
  text-align: right;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #543a5c, #452f4b);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.cart-item.free-delivery-warn .right-content {
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.cart-item.free-delivery-warn .right-content p {
  background: #bf2328;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 0 13px 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
}

.right-content:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 100%;
  left: -12px;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 12px 22px 0;
  border-color: transparent #bf2328 transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart-item free-delivery-warn">
  <div class="left">
    <p>Faltam apenas <span class="price-w">R$ 165,00</span> para você ganhar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-content">
    <p>Frete grátis&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-truck price-w"></i></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The tip you suggested was what I was forgetting. Thanks!